# Properly implement "save form and close" button in Angular

Tags: angular

I need to implement a button that once clicked, it will submit the form and go back    to the last page in the history. Going back to the last page is easy, I just need to to do this

this.location.back();

My problem is CanDeactivate gets fired when this.location.back() is executed. The canDeactivate method currently just checks if the form is dirty, and if it is, "You have unsaved changes" dialog will be displayed, AND you have to click "Leave" button to go back to the previous page. This behavior is confusing for the client especially if the form is successfully saved or submitted.

What I'm planning to do is.. after submitting the form, I'll set the model or form's isDirty property to false OR mark the form as pristine OR maybe reset the form, whichever is possible(I just started coding on angular so please have patience on me lol) so that when canDeactivate is fired, it will no longer see that the form is dirty hence "Unsaved changes" dialog will not be displayed.

I haven't started coding on that part yet, but I'd like to know if that sounds an acceptable and feasible way to implement that kind of feature.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After submitting your form just check if it was successfully posted and then reset your form and use location back

```js
this.myAPI.post(this.myForm.value).subscribe(res=>{
  
    console.log(res)
    this.myForm.reset()
    this.location.back()  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.myAPI.post(this.myForm.value).subscribe(res=>{
  
    console.log(res)
    this.myForm.reset()
    this.location.back()  
})
```